# createObjectURL returns null

Tags: javascript, url, safari, blob, web-sql

I use the following code to create URL's for blob's:

```
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

URL.createObjectURL(storedBlob);
```

I ensured that URL method exists, as well as the blob which looks like this from the debugger:

[image]

The code works fine on Firefox, Chrome and IE but on Safrari `createObjectURL` always returns `null`.

Edit.:

- Creating Object URL for fresh constructed Blob's like in [Chris
  Benselers fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLx4xt1h) works fine.
- I restore the blob from a WEBSQL Database ( I use it with [IndexedDBShim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) )

**What is the problem and how to solve it?**

Comment: What version of Safari?

Comment: With Safari 7.0.3 this sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kLx4xt1h/ worked fine.

Comment: 7.0.6 (9537.78.2), the fiddle worked fine for me too. I will ad further circiumstances to my question.